# Zabbix 3.4, Oracle Linux 7.4: Error with php-mbstring and php-bcmath

Tags: php, linux, zabbix

I have OS

```
NAME="Oracle Linux Server"
VERSION="7.4"
ID="ol"
VERSION_ID="7.4"
PRETTY_NAME="Oracle Linux Server 7.4"
ANSI_COLOR="0;31"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:oracle:linux:7:4:server"
HOME_URL="https://linux.oracle.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugzilla.oracle.com/"

ORACLE_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT="Oracle Linux 7"
ORACLE_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT_VERSION=7.4
ORACLE_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="Oracle Linux"
ORACLE_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION=7.4
```

Tried to install zabbix 3.4

```
 rpm -Uvh http://repo.zabbix.com/zabbix/3.4/rhel/7/x86_64/zabbix-release-3.4-1.el7.centos.noarch.rpm
```

and

```
yum install zabbix-server-mysql zabbix-web-mysql
```

and returned error

```
Error: Package: zabbix-web-3.4.1-1.el7.noarch (zabbix)
           Requires: php-mbstring
Error: Package: zabbix-web-3.4.1-1.el7.noarch (zabbix)
           Requires: php-bcmath
```

tried to installed

```
sudo yum install php-mbstring
```

returned

```
Loaded plugins: ulninfo
No package php-mbstring available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

tried to search

[root@zabbixapp01 zabbix]# yum search mbstring

```
Loaded plugins: ulninfo
Warning: No matches found for: mbstring
No matches found
```

[root@zabbixapp01 zabbix]# yum search bcmath

```
Loaded plugins: ulninfo
Warning: No matches found for: bcmath
No matches found
```

How to solve problem?

Comment: Seems to be also asked (more appropriately) on serverfault: https://serverfault.com/questions/874297/zabbix-3-4-oracle-linux-7-4-error-with-php-mbstring-and-php-bcmath .

Comment: ok, problem solve, please write answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

edited file with repo and added new repo

```
nano /etc/yum.repos.d/public-yum-ol7.repo


[ol7_optional_latest]
name=Oracle Linux $releasever Optional Latest ($basearch)
baseurl=http://yum.oracle.com/repo/OracleLinux/OL7/optional/latest/$basearch/
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-oracle
gpgcheck=1
enabled=1
```

after enabled new repo

```
yum clean all
yum-config-manager --enable ol7_optional_latest
```

checked status new repo

```
yum repolist all
```

must returned for example

```
!ol7_optional_latest/x86_64    Oracle Linux 7Server Optional Latest (x86_64)                                                        enabled: 12,831+3,515
```